# Chatfuel redirect_to_blocks does not work

Tags: json, facebook-chatbot, chatfuel

I have a problem with my chatfuel JSON API from my node JS app.
I try to catch an error and return a message + a redirect_to_block to be able to ask the user again.
My error detection works well and if I try to display a message only it works. My JSON is :

```
[{"text":"Please type again"}]
```

But I can't add a redirect_to_blocks to this (and I even loose the text message display).
I tried those solutions (and probably some more) but I think I didn't get the JSON structure :

```
// Solution 1 
[{ "message": { "text": "Please type again" }, "redirect_to_blocks": ["When?"] }]
// Solution 2 
[{ "messages": { "text": "Please type again" }, "block_names": ["When?"], "type": "show_block", "title": "go" }]
// Solution 3 
[{ "text": "Please type again" }, "redirect_to_blocks": ["When?"] }]
```

And here is the block I want to add (i'm not even sure the name I have to give to the JSON)

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Julian, workaround that works for me is returning from API following JSON:

```
{
  "set_attributes": {
     "redirectBlock": <your block name>
  }
}
```

and build structure in Chatfuel as below:

[Chatfuel flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXJSk.jpg)

Now you have a dispatcher that allows you to map values from API to block titles.

Answer (score 0):

I had your same issues,

I created a json request in my Flow that returns this json:

```
{ "redirect_to_blocks": ["Block name"] }
```

but Chatfuel never redirects to it.

I solved it creating a new block in "Automate" pane with same name and It works.

I know that it's passed much time since your question,
but I hope it can helps future issues.